# Find the average of a word

Tags: code-golf, string, keyboard

> Inspired by [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40172973#40172973)

Your task will be to take a word and find the average position of its letters on the keyboard as a letter.

### Keyboard Layout

Since layouts vary from keyboard to keyboard, we will be using a standard based of of my own keyboard in this question.

The keyboard has 3 rows, the top row from left to right contains the keys

```
QWERTYUIOP
```

The second row contains the letters

```
ASDFGHJKL
```

The final row contains

```
ZXCVBNM
```

Each letter is 1 unit horizontal from its neighbor to the left.  This means that `W` is 1 away from `Q` and `E` is 1 away from `W` and so on.

The keys at the beginning of each row have the positions:

```
Q : 0,0
A : 1/3,1
Z : 2/3,2
```

This means that the rows are separated one unit vertically and the bottom two rows are shifted by a third from the row above them.

---

You should take a word as input and output the letter that is closest to the average position of the letters in its word.  The average of a set of vectors is

```
(average x value, average y value)
```

When two keys are equidistant from the average you may output either as the "closest" key.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

### Example solution

Let's calculate the average of `APL`.

We convert each letter to a vector

```
A -> (1/3,1)
P -> (9,0)
L -> (8 1/3,1)
```

We add these up the three vectors to get `(17 2/3, 2)`. We then divide each coordinate by 3 (The number of letters in the word) to get `(5 8/9, 2/3)`.

The closest letter to `(5 8/9, 2/3)` is `J` at `(6 1/3,1)` so our result is `J`.

### Test Cases

```
APL  -> J
TEXT -> R
PPCG -> J
QQQQ -> Q
ZZZZ -> Z
PPPP -> P
MMMM -> M
QQSS -> A or W
```

Comment: May the I/O be lowercase, or is uppercase mandatory?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You can do lower case.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 130 bytes

```python
lambda w,d={'QAZWSXEDCRFVTGBYHNUJMIKOOLPP'[i]:i%3*1j+i/3for i in range(28)}:min(d,key=lambda c:abs(d[c]-sum(map(d.get,w))/len(w)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TdBNb4JAEAbgu79ikqbZ3Yo1lktDQhO0fktdhFaLelhd0FVZCWKMafrb6R6qy3uZw5OZyUx6zbdHaRaxvSgOLFlxBheD2z/Ic8KpP2u/tyadr6Db/O59fA7c/nA8HlGK5mJpiUfzqbGriroZHzMQICRkTG4i/PJKfq1ESMyNfXS1/6euLbY6YT5fL2unc4ITlmL@vIly40JI/RBJrCop0kzIHMcYOXSECBCAB6i9waByh6A9CxC5wUQDpa2uhlKHp6LB0xCqaAjLo9SNd6AaXBUNbnmH72twQH1kWin@AA)

`d={'QAZWSXEDCRFVTGBYHNUJMIKOOLPP'[i]:i%3*1j+i/3for i in range(28)}` constructs the mapping from letters to points (represented as complex numbers, `(x+y*1j)`).

As for the lambda body, `sum(map(d.get,w))/len(w)` computes the average position of word `w`, and putting that in `min(d,key=lambda c:abs(d[c]-…))` finds the closest letter to that position. (For complex numbers, `abs(A-B)` corresponds to the Euclidean distance between `(A.real, A.imag)` and `(B.real, B.imag)`.)

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 250 + 13 bytes

+13 bytes for `using System;`

```cs
n=>{var a=new[]{"QWERTYUIOP","ASDFGHJKL","ZXCVBNM"};float x=0,y=0;int i=0,j=0,l=n.Length;foreach(char c in n){for(i=0,j=0;i<2;){if(a[i][j]==c)break;if(++j>=a[i].Length){i++;j=0;}}x+=j;y+=i;}return a[(int)Math.Round(y/3)][(int)Math.Round(x/l+y/l/3)];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVHLbsIwEDzDV6xyihUaUHs0RqIU6APa8GihjXJwjQOmwZFsQ4mifHvqiIhLLVle7eyMd2eZvmGp4uVRC7mFRaYNP@AmS6jWEKh0q@gB8mZDG2oEg1MqNjClQrraKEsII6Bqq1FV0riQ/dFRsu4FbgHbUdWDGEgpSS8/UQWUSP4bRrkzWw3ny8/3p7fAaTn9xcNo/Pj8MrHx13rwcf86dQocJyk1cCadVkY6WEgDwsZ7exMi/QmXW7PDsW2fsp1bfQUMhASJcpt061osurcY5SJ2aSiicB8RwtC35fxgm/O8fY9UQC1nCz0PV7SiOHtkjzOPCFwobo5KAg1d2wWaUrPz5@lRbtysfYeif9lzO/GydlJhuChxo2HtuTpmuDaMaq6BgPUCrkAOTj@wDoCzHK6X1RsEg3H1zuxxoMBWph4X6g2Aria@SqJ6hf4glTpNuL9SwvCJkNyNXY2QVSiaRfkH)

<sub>Little sidenote: This outputs `F` for `TEXT`, since that was the original desired output.

Outputting `R` instead of `F` was changed after this answer was posted.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 37 bytes

```
ØQi€µT÷3Ḣ+Ṁ;T
Ç€ZÆmðạ²SðÐ€ØAÇ€¤iṂ$ịØA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjMDMR01rDm0NObzd@OGORdoPdzZYh3AdbgcKRh1uyz284eGuhYc2BR/ecHgCUOjwDEew1KElmQ93Nqk83N0NFPn/H6Lm0N7/So4BPkoA)

lol way too long

## Explanation

```
ØQi€µT÷3Ḣ+Ṁ;T            Helper Link; compute the position of a key
   €                     For each row of
ØQ                       ["QWERTYUIOP", "ASDFGHJKL", "ZXCVBNM"] (hooray for builtins)
  i                      Find the first occurrence of the argument
    µ                    Start a new monadic chain
     T                   List of indices of truthy values; singleton list with the row of the key
      ÷                  Divide the index by
       3                 3
        Ḣ                Take the first element
         +               Add it to the original list
          Ṁ              Take the maximum (the adjusted horizontal position of the key)
           ;             Append
            T            The index of the truthy value (the row)
Ç€ZÆmðạ²SðÐ€ØAÇ€¤iṂ$ịØA  Main Link
 €                       For each character in the input
Ç                        Compute its position using the helper link
  Z                      Zip (all of the horizontal positions are in the first list; all of the vertical positions are in the second list)
   Æm                    Take the arithmetic mean (of each sublist)
     ðạ²Sð               Dyadic chain to compute the distance (squared) between two coordinates
      ạ                  Take the absolute difference between each coordinate value (auto-vectorization)
       ²                 Square each value
        S                Take the sum (returns the distance squared but for comparison that's fine)
          Ð€             Take the distance between the mean position and each element in
            ØAÇ€¤        [Nilad:] the positions of each character in the uppercase alphabet
               €         For each character in
            ØA           "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
              Ç          Compute its position
                 iṂ$     Find the index of the minimum (closest)
                 i       First occurrence of             in the list of distances
                  Ṃ                          the minimum
                    ị    Index back into
                     ØA  The alphabet
```

Comment: @downvoter the issue with the test case has been fixed; please remove your downvote or explain why you wish to downvote my answer

Comment: I think it disagrees again? `F` doesn't seem to be an allowed output anymore...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Ah okay I didn't update that remark after FCM corrected the test case

Comment: Somehow Mathematica doesn't have a bultin for keyboard rows.

Comment: @Razetime did you mean to comment somewhere else, this isn't Mathematica lol

Comment: no, it was strange to see a builtin that was in Jelly but not mathematica :P

Comment: @Razetime ah, I see. yeah finding something mathematica doesn't just have a builtin for is always pretty rare :D

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 166 bytes

```js
f=
s=>[...s].map(c=>(h+=c=s.search(c),v+=c%3,l++),h=v=l=0,s='QAZWSXEDCRFVTGBYHNUJMIKKOLLP')&&[...s].map((c,i)=>(i=(i-h/l)*(i-h/l)+(i=i%3-v/l)*i*9,i)<m&&(m=i,r=c),m=9)&&r
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=/^[A-Z]+$/.test(this.value)?f(this.value):``><pre id=o>
```

6 bytes could be saved by switching to ES7. Previous 131-byte solution used a simplistic distance check which is no longer acceptable.

```js
f=
s=>([...s].map(c=>(h+=c=s.search(c),v+=c%3,l++),h=v=l=0,s='QAZWSXEDCRFVTGBYHNUJMIKKOLLP'),v=(v/l+.5|0),h=((h/l-v)/3+.5|0),s[h*3+v])
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=/^[A-Z]+$/.test(this.value)?f(this.value):``><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>257 243 242</s> 237 bytes

```
char h(String s){int l=s.length(),i=l+28;s="QAZWSXEDCRFVTGBYHNUJMIK<OL>P"+s;float d=9,x=0,y=0,e;for(;i>28;y+=(e=s.indexOf(s.charAt(--i)))%3/l,x+=e/3/l);for(;i-->0;)if((e=(x-i/3f)*(x-i/3f)+(y-i%3)*(y-i%3))<d){d=e;l=i;}return s.charAt(l);}
```

Saved 14 bytes - the distance away from the best key will be less than 3 units

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>452</s> <s>431</s> <s>424</s> <s>400</s> <s>389</s> <s>324</s> <s>322</s> <s>296</s> <s>285</s> <s>281</s> <s>276</s> <s>274</s> <s>260</s> <s>258</s> 257 bytes

Something to start golfing from

```java
s->{String c="QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKL;ZXCVBNM";int i=0,r=0,l=0;double x=0,y=0,D=99,t,f=s.length();for(;i<f;x+=l%10+l/10/3d,y+=l/10)l=c.indexOf(s.charAt(i++));for(;r<27;r++)if(D>(t=Math.pow(x/f-r/10/3d-r%10,2)+Math.pow(y/f-r/10,2))){D=t;l=r;}return c.charAt(l);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBbT8IwFH7nVzQkJp3bysUHQ0pJkIlXRJx340PdBYqlXbozZCH8diwyjSc5Sb9LT3u@OV9yX2eJmsefW7HItAE0txwBsUjIIa395woQkqSFikBotRNrkeR5jvpoXUO2cuAgIjSsHN0QjFBTbzDjhkeQmJ5m29zvrfc8ilh98nR6d//ycDG@7YfB8Oz88uqavj4PHk9uRnUqFCDBmp6xLVmTxrr4kAlaWVjaDlin44GXspzIRE1hhh2aaoOp6KZ05TJ50Gq6stFqNo5ir7TYHh3JIiJUnKzGKc5JZH/WByxc16numm77mBqLRYqDHgY24jAjmf7Cq0bqm/0039jRXttx/8SyEi3pOOuAAZXM0I1JoDAKRb8PSYdutja2XViZXcaGVWW21CJGCy4U3ofz9o64meZOleyuwjKHZEF0ASSzFpAKa8KzTJa4PpmEYd3u8GPe1Dbbbw)

Comment: Gives me the wrong result for `TEXT`.

Comment: @IanH. It gives me 'R' which is what OP asked for

Comment: Didn't see that was changed in the task, my bad.

Comment: [431 bytes](https://tio.run/##fVJNU9swEL3nV2h8QcK2As1RVmZcDP1KgJJCaZlMR3WcRK5jaeQVtcfj3x7k1BR6qU67b99@PuXiUYRKZ2W@@rWXO60MoNxhFOQuo8ds9BqzIAu6tmUKUpV9cJQWoqpQjNoRcq8CATJFFwMjWoCR5SY42wojUsjMVPF9FU7bP/jDMuXe56/nN1@@3X64ug7iRXLx7v3HT7Pg@/3Z3dvLuUcrXUjAXuARtlL2Z5Ghmp8EDT9ha2WwLAFJZ8uookVWbmCLCZO@T/rgwM9dPI8mLHewXOP0oc8i@ZLKcpXVV2tc0dSNFwOWhEzDU9LWPs/HE///TNY4FuvqMX/VuvnH68lI8yN09Dx7wpODQefx/Y@7eHZ7HtjAHFYxbkwTpUM2M8MS1sE2GkYxy5fi1hHaoSzwuYAt1eo3rkNzjE/HExLa4A3x/@JNaJzP3AEgSkibcGCav5Qd9jq4lrCuMxlYUyLNur0TuZdWu1ZO2kHhRyVXaCdkiZ@lRMJsKjL8g/4tmgqyHVUWqHYUKEqsqNC6aLAXX888d8MDtxt1@yc).

Comment: I hadn't seen this answer when I posted mine, should I have suggested mine as a comment or are multiple answers for the same language ok?

Comment: @Tahg Multiple are fine, nice one for beating me!

Comment: `for(;i<f;l=c.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)),x+=l%10+l/10/3d,y+=l/10);` can be golfed to `
//for(;i<f;x+=l%10+l/10/3d,y+=l/10)l=c.indexOf(s.charAt(i++));`

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 79 bytes

```
≔⪪”$±=Ｋ≕⦃Vj@η⟲.w\`o:7➙1”¶ηＦθＦ³Ｆ⌕Ａ§ηκι⊞υ⟦λκ⟧ＩＥ²∕ΣＥυ§λιＬθ§§η⁺·⁵∕ΣＥυ⊟ιＬθ⁺·⁵∕ΣＥυ⊟ιＬθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY07b8IwFIX3/grL07VkGIqYmMyrpITWkLa8whAlKbZwnTR2EP/eWFEjIcHUuxzp6LvfSUVSpUWinGPGyKOGqFTSAl6uJ6uP7WfwzmPNovH0ZfY6D2O924y@hm8LTBGONSYUCTJ4@i4qBL8ENdn7y6nUGVMKmA10ll9AUHTyvCQE8doIqCnaK98dvIBXUlsYJcbCIinhmaKxPMssh6j@aRoPtx7VOLwpzPXRCr/rr1W00M0oV7WBbv@Rkhcl3Lv@8UIGzu0x4yE@uI46XwE)

Neil's golf using string functions.

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 107 bytes

```
Ｐ”$±=Ｋ≕⦃Vj@η⟲.w\`o:7➙1”≔⟦⟧α≔⟦⟧βＦχ«Ｆ³«ＪικＦθ«¿⁼λＫＫ«⊞α⎇›ⅉ⁰⁺∕¹¦³ⅈⅈ⊞βⅉ»»»»Ｊ⌊∕⁺Σα·⁵Ｌθ⌈∕⁺Σβ·⁵Ｌθ≔ＫＫχ⎚χ¶Ｉ∕ΣαＬθ¶Ｉ∕ΣβＬθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVDbTsJAEH1mv4L0aSYZTQnxA7BcpIJWqVfKw7audMOylW1LQgjfXttaDIYXk93knMmcc2YmirmJEq6KYpqrTHpG6gysh5fBo//2NL73At2b9YejG/d2Euj3V@f5@m5qIeulqVxqmC@In5IQ2TAx0LFxz1oV6lag5ebrLz8BSSssWVXf1PWW/ITBJucqBUWeECtAxPbey9MYOPnCaG52MDKCZ8KASzaSp/IU@nIrPwR0qIs0rh62K7daF5KLh5KV/8AOrIkeqqRMbXS1xyxfA0eyL6@QJkIvs7gcCpEcIdVZY3je@Lt2NTdFyBwluGE/Byxpc8lAW0fs8DQ7OjfpJ37/EIR/BEUxt3rexFoUF2r7DQ)

Draws the keyboard on the canvas and finds the average that way.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
Æịµ÷3Ċ+
ØQœiⱮÇÆmØQŒṪ¤Çạ¥ÐṂœịØQX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w28Pd3Ye2Ht5ufKRLm@vwjMCjkzMfbVx3uP1wWy6IN@nhzlWHlhxuf7hr4aGlhyc83Nl0dDJQB1Aq4v/DHZsOtz9qWhP5/79jgI9CiGtEiEJAgLO7QiAQKEQBAZAbEKDgCwRAseBgAA)

Uses some features that were presumably not implemented when HyperNeutrino wrote his solution, so considering this only beats it by <s><sup>4</sup></s> 6 bytes, I wouldn't be surprised if a modernized version of his would come out shorter--but I started writing this before I even noticed his existed.

```
Æịµ÷3Ḟ+                    Helper link (monadic):
Æị                         convert list to complex,
  µ   +                    add the complex number to
     Ċ                     the imaginary part of
   ÷3                      its quotient by 3.

ØQœiⱮÇÆmØQŒṪ¤Çạ¥ÐṂœịØQX    Main link:
ØQœiⱮ                      multidimensional indices of input in QWERTY layout,
     Ç                     apply helper link,
      Æm                   average;
        ØQŒṪ¤              for all multidimensional indices in the layout
                ÐṂ         keep those with the smallest
              ạ¥           absolute difference between the average and
             Ç             their result from the helper link;
                  œịØQ     index back into QWERTY
                      X    and choose one key at random.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 44 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žVIšεεžVsδkDZkDŠ3/+à‚]ćøÅA`UòDžVsèŠè€θDX.xkè
```

Not too happy with it, but it works.. :/ Can definitely be golfed some more using a different approach.

I/O in lowercase.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4wz6MLz209txXIKj63JdslKtvl6AJjfe3DCx41zIo90n54x@FWx4TQw5tcQCoOrzi64PCKR01rzu1widCryD684v//xIIcAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSvdL/o/vCKo8uPLf13FYgq/jclmyXqGyXowuM9bUPL3jUMCv2SPvhHYdbHRNCD29yAak4vOLogsMrHjWtObfDJUKvIvvwiv9KemE6/6OVEgtylHSUSlKLS4BUQUFyOpAqBAIgVQUEYMGCAiCVCwRgueJipVgA).

**Explanation:**

Step 1: create a list with all the coordinate-values, and convert the input in a similar matter as well:

```python
žV                     # Push builtin ["qwertyuiop","asdfghjkl","zxcvbnm"]
  Iš                   # Prepend the input-string to this list
    ε                  # Map over each string:
     ε                 #  Inner map over each individual character:
      žV               #   Push ["qwertyuiop","asdfghjkl","zxcvbnm"] again
        s              #   Swap so the current character is at the top of the stack
         δk            #   Get the index of this character in each of the three strings
                       #   (or -1 if it's not found)
           D           #   Duplicate this list of indices
            Z          #   Get the largest index (without popping)
             k         #   Get the index of this largest index in the triplet
              D        #   Duplicate this index
               Š       #   Triple swap the three values on the stack (a,b,c→c,a,b)
                3/     #   Divide it by 3
                  +    #   Add it to each index in the list we duplicated
                   à   #   Pop and push the maximum again
                    ‚  #   And pair it with the duplicated & triple-swapped index
    ]                  # Close the nested maps
```

[Try just this first step.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4wz6MLz209txXIKj63JdslKtvl6AJjfe3DCx41zIr9/z@xIAcA)

Step 2: get the average coordinate of the input:

```python
ć                      # Extract head; pop and push remainder-list and first item separated
 ø                     # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
  ÅA                   # Get the arithmetic mean of both inner triplets
```

[Try just the first two steps.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4wz6MLz209txXIKj63JdslKtvl6AJjfe3DCx41zIo90n54x@FWx///EwtyAA)

Step 3: get the coordinate closest to this average coordinate, and convert it back to a character to output:

```python
`                      # Pop and push both separated to the stack
 U                     # Pop and store the second one in variable `X`
  ò                    # Round the first value to the nearest integer
   D                   # Duplicate this integer
    žV                 # Push ["qwertyuiop","asdfghjkl","zxcvbnm"] yet again
      s                # Swap so the integer is at the top of the stack
       è               # Index it into the list of strings
        Š              # Triple-swap the values on the stack (a,b,c→c,a,b)
         è             # Index the duplicated integer into the remainder-list
          €θ           # Leave the last value of each inner pair
            D          # Duplicate the list
             X.x       # Pop the copy and leave the value closest to value `X`
                k      # Get the index of this value in the duplicated list
                 è     # And index it into the string we triple-swapped
                       # (after which this character is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 234 bytes

```
(r=(K=Round)@Mean[If[(w=First[q=#&@@Position[(s=X/@{"QWERTYUIOP","ASDFGHJKL","ZXCVBNM"}),#]])==1,q=q-1,If[w==2,q=q+{-1,-2/3},q=q+{-1,-1/3}]]&/@(X=Characters)@#];z=If[(h=#&@@r)==0,r=r+1,If[h==1,r=r+{1,2/3},r=r+{1,1/3}]];s[[##]]&@@K@z)&
```

Comment: Fixed! works for all test cases.